# Cannot access specific website - jsfiddle.net

Tags: networking, router

For some reason, as of last week, I'm no longer able to access [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Pinging it gives me a `Request timed out` error. This is what I have tried so far:

1. ipconfig release/renew, flushed DNS
2. used different browsers (and even different devices, connected to my network)
3. emailed the JSFiddle support team and asked if my IP was blocked for some reason (it
   was not)

I can access the website using my phone through cellular data, but not when connected to my Wi-Fi - which makes me thing there's an issue with my network somehow. This is what I got from running tracert:

```
  1    9ms     6ms    8ms    mycomputer [0.0.0.0]
  2    17ms   26ms   13ms    c9110007.virtua.com.br [201.17.0.7] 
  3    10ms   10ms   10ms    embratel-t0-4-0-0-uacc03.rjoen.embratel.net.br [201.30.79.13]
  4    13ms    11ms  14ms    200.244.216.16 
  5   139ms   131ms 137ms    ebt-p0-5-3-0-intl02.nyk.embratel.net.br [200.230.252.122]
  6   129ms   130ms 128ms    ae-23.r06.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.195.45] 
  7   120 ms  120ms 123ms    xe-0-4-0-10.r06.nycmny01.us.ce.gin.ntt.net [129.250.204.106] 
  8   125ms   133ms 124ms    192.241.164.238 
  9     *        *        *      Request timed out. 
  10    *        *        *      Request timed out.  
  11    *        *        *      Request timed out. 
  12    *        *        *      Request timed out.
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the last two hops on my trace are:

```
14    62 ms    68 ms    70 ms  192.241.164.238
15    68 ms    60 ms    70 ms  162.243.204.190
Trace complete.
```

The packets are being dropped by their server (probably by a firewall). You should email them with this information and see if they can offer any additional insight on why your IP might be blocked.

Comment: It was indeed blocked on their end, even though they said it wasn't when I first asked. Thanks!